# How do I superimpose a frequency polygon on top of a histogram in R using lines?

Tags: r, histogram

I'm a beginner at R and RStudio and I'm trying to make a frequency polygon on top of a histogram using the "cars" dataset.

```
attach(cars)
hist(speed)
lines(speed, lwd=2, col = "royalblue")
```

[This is the output I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faRJ4.png)

What I need is the points coming properly on top of the histogram. I have seen [this one using plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937192/how-do-i-superimpose-a-frequency-polygon-on-top-of-a-histogram-in-r) but I can't get to use it in my code.

[This is the output I need (It's an example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bmBc.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fitting a density curve to a histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r)

Comment: @jay.sf It's close but the problem is that it's a density curve but I need a frequency polygon. [Here is what I hope to achieve](https://i.imgur.com/s6B7pcM.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, see here how to make a great reproducible R example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @VaishnavSanthosh Ah ok, didn't notice the difference, see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hist()` has a hidden output which you can grab by assignment. Then feed `lines()` with it.

```
h <- hist(x, col=5)
lines(x=c(0, h$mids, tail(h$mids, 1) + el(diff(h$mids))), y=c(0, h$counts, 0), lwd=2)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(22522)
x <- rpois(50, 6)
```

Comment: This might be it but is there any way to mark the points on the middle of the bar [rather than than it shiftting to the left side?](https://i.imgur.com/XnMdVVi.png)

Comment: @VaishnavSanthosh Yes, I found already the `mids` in `h`,  please see edit.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
hist(speed)
lines(speed, lwd=2, col = "royalblue")
```

Alternatively, you can do it all at once in ggplot2. But I would need a data sample and your script.

Best

Comment: We haven't learnt ggplot2 so we can't use it. Also the data sample is the cars dataset. I have used attach(cars) for it.